# Attribute modification within a class

Tags: java

I have the method getPlan and I try to modify an object (attribute in my class)

```
class XYZ

/**
 * Plan.
 */
private Plan plan;

@Override
public final Plan getPlan() {
    subjects.addAll(plan.getSubjects());
    ...
    return new Plan("1", subjects.size(), subjects);
}

@Override
public final Graph createGraph() {
    Plan fPlan = getPlan();
    ...
    return graph;
}
```

In the second method createGraph, I try to get the modified object (fPlan), but it's in the initial state (Plan plan).  I hope you understand the situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I pass the "plan" object in another class and I want to modify it for intern use within XYZ class.

Comment: I don't see your `plan` attribute on the lefthand side of an assignment operation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your method should not return a `Plan`, because `Plan plan` is an instance variable already. Plus you don't instantiate `Plan plan` anyway, so I guess you have to pick one of below pieces of code:

First piece: we make `Plan plan` an instance variable, and edit, modify and use that and only that. That means in this class, we don't have to return an `Plans`, as we have access to `Plan plan` in this instance of `xyz`.

```
class XYZ

private Plan plan;

@Override
public final void instantiatePlan() {
    subjects.addAll(plan.getSubjects());
    ...
    plan = new Plan("1", subjects.size(), subjects);
}

@Override
public final Graph createGraph() {
    plan = instantiatePlan();
    ...
    return graph;
}
```

second option: we remove the instance variable `Plan plan`, and in `createGraph()`, we call `getPlan()` with returns a `Plan` which we can modify and edit there. According to what I guess your context is, I'd go for the first option though.

```
class XYZ

@Override
public final Plan getPlan() {
    subjects.addAll(plan.getSubjects());
    ...
    return new Plan("1", subjects.size(), subjects);
}

@Override
public final Graph createGraph() {
    Plan fPlan = getPlan();
    ...
    //edit fPlan here.
    return graph;
}
```

EDIT: Seeing your comment, I understand even less of your problem. First of all, in `getPlan()` you call `getSubjects()` on `Plan plan`, but it's not even instantiated, so it'll throw an NPE immediately. Second: let a method do what the name tells you: thus, `getPlan()` should just be `return plan;`, no more, no less, no editing, modifying in that method. I'd suggest making a constructor of class `XYZ` with params `Plan plan`:

```
public XYZ(Plan mPlan) {
    this.plan = mPlan;
}
```

Or initializing it in the constructor:

```
public XYZ(ArrayList<Subject> subjects) {
    this.plan = new Plan("1", subjects.size(), subjects);
}
```

Please tell where you want `plan` to be what.

Comment: Thank you. I use the second option, but without removing the object, but rather with calling the method outside the class.